# SQL: How to group data in a table by date, and join it with another table to display account numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I am using a database in SQL Server 2008.  Not very good at SQL, and I have read quite a few questions and answers on here that have left me more confused than before.  I have almost got this query working, but it's not quite right and looks very inefficient.

I am looking at sales data, and I want to return the amount sold for each 90-day period over the last year for each account.  Some of those accounts sold nothing during a 90-day period.  The tables look like this:

`logistics_distributorgrowth`:

```
[id].....[customer].....[type].....[show]
-----------------------------------------
99.......11891..........customer...yes
```

and so on

`InvoiceHold`:

```
AccountNumber.....Price.....QtyShipped.....InvoiceDate
------------------------------------------------------    
11891.............250.......50.............2013-10-12
```

and so on

So far, this is the query I have come up with, using temp tables to get each group of data.  The problem is that since I am using one of the tables to get the account number, if there were no sales in that time period, then that account number is not in the temp table for that time period, so in the result table there will be rows with a NULL account number and sales numbers for the other three periods.

I'm sorry, I don't know how to format the code.  Can someone help?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Q4Table') IS NOT NULL
TRUNCATE TABLE #Q4Table
ELSE
CREATE TABLE #Q4Table (Account int,Total int)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Q3Table') IS NOT NULL
TRUNCATE TABLE #Q3Table
ELSE
CREATE TABLE #Q3Table (Account int,Total int)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Q2Table') IS NOT NULL
TRUNCATE TABLE #Q2Table
ELSE
CREATE TABLE #Q2Table (Account int,Total int)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Q1Table') IS NOT NULL
TRUNCATE TABLE #Q1Table
ELSE
CREATE TABLE #Q1Table (Account int,Total int)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#acctNo') IS NOT NULL
TRUNCATE TABLE #acctNo
ELSE
CREATE TABLE #acctNo (Account int)

INSERT INTO #Q4Table
select AccountNumber, 
SUM(Price * QtyShipped)
from Datahub..InvoiceHold
where AccountNumber in (Select customer from [Logistics].[dbo].[logistics_distributorgrowth] where [type] = 'customer' and show = 'yes')
and QtyShipped > 0
AND InvoiceDate BETWEEN cast(GETDATE() - 360 as date) AND cast(GETDATE() - 270 as date)
group by AccountNumber

INSERT INTO #Q3Table
select AccountNumber, 
SUM(Price * QtyShipped)
from Datahub..InvoiceHold
where AccountNumber in (Select customer from [Logistics].[dbo].[logistics_distributorgrowth] where [type] = 'customer' and show = 'yes')
and QtyShipped > 0
AND InvoiceDate BETWEEN cast(GETDATE() - 270 as date) AND cast(GETDATE() - 180 as date)
group by AccountNumber

INSERT INTO #Q2Table
select AccountNumber, 
SUM(Price * QtyShipped)
from Datahub..InvoiceHold
where AccountNumber in (Select customer from [Logistics].[dbo].[logistics_distributorgrowth] where [type] = 'customer' and show = 'yes')
and QtyShipped > 0
AND InvoiceDate BETWEEN cast(GETDATE() - 180 as date) AND cast(GETDATE() - 90 as date)
group by AccountNumber

INSERT INTO #Q1Table
select AccountNumber, 
SUM(Price * QtyShipped)
from Datahub..InvoiceHold
where AccountNumber in (Select customer from [Logistics].[dbo].[logistics_distributorgrowth] where [type] = 'customer' and show = 'yes')
and QtyShipped > 0
AND InvoiceDate BETWEEN cast(GETDATE() - 90 as date) AND cast(GETDATE() as date)
group by AccountNumber

INSERT INTO #acctNo
select Account from #Q1Table
union
select Account from #Q2Table
union
select Account from #Q3Table
union
select Account from #Q4Table


select acct.Account, a.Total '360 to 270 days ago', b.Total '270 to 180 days ago', c.Total '180 to 90 days ago', d.Total '90 to 0 days ago' 
from #acctNo acct
full outer join #Q4Table a on acct.Account = a.Account
full outer join #Q3Table b on a.Account = b.Account
full outer join #Q2Table c on b.Account = c.Account
full outer join #Q1Table d on c.Account = d.Account
order by a.Account
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (I also fixed the borders between grouping so invoices don't get double counted):

```
SELECT  AccountNumber
      , SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, InvoiceDate, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 271 AND 360
                 THEN QtyShipped
            END * Price) '360 to 271 days ago'
      , SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, InvoiceDate, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 181 AND 270
                 THEN QtyShipped
            END * Price) '270 to 181 days ago'
      , SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, InvoiceDate, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 91 AND 180
                 THEN QtyShipped
            END * Price) '180 to 91 days ago'
      , SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, InvoiceDate, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 90
                 THEN QtyShipped
            END * Price) '90 to 0 days ago'
FROM    Datahub..InvoiceHold
WHERE   AccountNumber IN (
        SELECT  customer
        FROM    [Logistics].[dbo].[logistics_distributorgrowth]
        WHERE   [type] = 'customer'
                AND show = 'yes' )
        AND QtyShipped > 0
        AND InvoiceDate >= DATEADD(d, -360, GETDATE())
GROUP BY AccountNumber
```